# Async task in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous

Can execute an async task from a Controller in Laravel? I have tried doing so with Queues but I cannot.

Route:

```
Route::post('/loadimages', LoadImagesController@load')->name('loadimages');
```

Controller:

```
public function load(Request $request)
{
    $urls_array = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $request->urls);

    **// I want this task in the background...**
    DownloadImagesJob::dispatch($urls_array);

    **// ... and return immediately**
    return view('home');
}
```

ShouldQueue:

```
class DownloadImagesJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $urls;

    public function __construct(array $urls)
    {
        $this->urls = $urls;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // El código que quiero que se ejecute asíncronamente.
    }
}
```

I am using "database" driver so in config/queues.php:

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database'),
```

And:

```
 php artisan queue:table
 php artisan migrate
```

But the task is not running asynchronously.

Comment: Have you started the queue? `php artisan queue:work --tries=3`

Comment: Yes, I did it: `php artisan queue:work` but this command not finished, is it?

Comment: Have you checked the jobs and failed_jobs tables in the database and/or looked at the storage/logs/laravel.log?

Comment: Yes, all is empty.

Comment: what code are you running in the handle method?

Comment: Basically it receives an array with URL images and then it downloads them in storage folder:
        `foreach ($this->urls as $url) {
            $filename = basename($url);
            Storage::put($filename, file_get_contents($url));
        }` The app is very simple: there is a textarea in a form where user write all URL images and then my Laravel app download all these images in my server.

Comment: hmm, not sure. Without seeing any logs, it's a guessing game. What is APP_LOG_LEVEL set to in .env?

Comment: In my .env I don't have any APP_LOG_LEVEL entry. In app/config.php I have `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),`. Anyway, I am testing my app with artisan server: `php artisan serve` This server can doing async tasks?? Can be it the issue?

Comment: Maybe the `.env` file has `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync` which overwrite `'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'database')`

Comment: Yes , that was the problem... I had to change the config option on .env and config/queue.php